# Count the same word in different columns in a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, count

I have a data frame that contains different demographic data of the head of the household and the family members. I would like to count the total number of females and males in the whole data frame. The `value_counts()` only pull the count from one column, how do I count all the columns. Can `df['Column_Name'].value_counts()` take multiple columns containing the same values?

The columns are:
Applicant Name, Applicant Gender, Household Member 2 Name, Household Member 2 Gender, Household Member 3 Name, Household Member 3 Gender.

The values in the columns of Applicant Gender, Household Member 2 Gender, and Household Member 3 Gender are either Female or Male

Comment: You should illustrate better what the values are for this dataframe so we can have an idea on how to count them.

Comment: @luka1156 - on the 'Applicant Gender', 'Household Member 2 Gender' and 'Household Member 3 Gender' columns, the only values are either Female or Male.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the idea right, this should work.

```
males = df[(df['Applicant Gender'] == 'Male') & (df['Household Member 2 Gender'] == 'Male') & (df['Household Member 3 Gender'] == 'Male')].count().sum()

females = df[(df['Applicant Gender'] == 'Female') & (df['Household Member 2 Gender'] == 'Female') & (df['Household Member 3 Gender'] == 'Female')].count().sum()
```